# attempt to call field 'Random' (a nil value) error in lua when calling math.Random

Tags: lua, coronasdk

The following is my code

```
local myRandomNumber = math.Random(0,10) 
local egg=display.newImage("egg.jpg")
egg.numberValue=myRandomNumber
```

I get the following error
attempt to call field 'Random' (a nil value)

How can I solve this?

Also if I wanted the numberValue(i.e the random number generated) to be displayed on the image. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Did you mean [`math.random`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-math.random)?

Comment: Thankyou...that fixed the error!!!....Also could you plz tell me if I wanted the numberValue(i.e the random number generated) to be displayed on the image. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Lua is infected by "everything is case-sensitive" ideology.  Probably because of close relationship with C language.

Comment: No idea. If you can't find anything in the documentation about doing that sort of compositing/etc. then that sounds like it might be a reasonable question itself.

Comment: @EtanReisner Please make your statement an answer, so that the question can be formally answered.

Comment: @NicolBolas This is just a plain-and-simple typo as far as I'm concerned. This isn't something that's likely to help anyone else in the future.

Comment: I gladly submitted an answer. Press the green check to help future users.

Comment: I submitted an answer. Press the green check If it is helpful for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the basics of [Lua](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/start/introLua/index.html), Lua is a case-sensitive language.

SO , You need to implement `math.random` instead of `math.Random` .
Try this code now.

```
local myRandomNumber = math.random(0,10) 
local egg=display.newImage("egg.jpg")
egg.numberValue=myRandomNumber
```

Hope it will work for you .

Answer (score 0):

The function isn't capitalized, it's `math.random` you're looking for, not `math.Random`

All functions in the standard Lua libraries follow this rule.